# GetFileByServerRelativeUrl is not working for special characters

Tags: sharepoint-online, urldecode

I am downloading excel files from SharePoint using Python. All works fine except when excel file has special character. below two URLs for reference. I am using URL encoding (import urllib) and works fine for all URLs excepts file has special character. Any idea on what to do?

```
     working fine
    _api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/11/Documents/C%20F%20D/R%20C%20F%2020200501%20-%20Tecks%20comment.xlsm')/$value
     
     Not working 

    _api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/11/Documents/C%20F%20D/K%20%27%20%27%20-%20%27test.xlsm?')/$value')
    file name is -K ' ' - 'test.xlsm
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode all special characters,then use this rest:

```
/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/sites/dev/Doc/%2520sdff%5E%253d654fd.xlsx')
```

My file name is:`%20sdff^%3d654fd.xlsx`